# Two structs having same receiver function implementations, how to remove the duplications

Tags: go, struct

I have two structs that are having same receiver function implementations:

```
type A struct {
    name string
    // other fields
}

type B struct {
    name string
    // other fields
}

type AA struct {
    resource A
}

func (a *AA) Get() string {
    // process something with a.resource.name
    return a.resource.name
}

type BB struct {
    resource B
}

func (b *BB) Get() string {
    // process something with b.resource.name
    return b.resource.name
}

type I interface {
    Get() string
}
```

both structs `AA` and `BB` have `Get` function, in order to satisfy the interface `I`, this might be a dumb question, but I dont know how I can simplify them to remove the duplications of two `Get` functions, tried:

1. having a generic struct and embedded in `A` & `B` - cant do this due
   to json serializations in the system I use.
2. embedded `AA` in `BB` and calling `AA.Get` - wont work since name is inside `B` instead of `A`
3. Combine `AA` and `BB` with both fields like `resourceA` and `resourceB` - this complicates the `Get` function, since then it needs to handle
4. create a non-receiver function and use it for both `AA` and `BB` - this can work but since there are quite some fields I need, not just `name`, so the function will end up with quite many parameters.

I cant stop feeling there should be an easier way, and also trying/googling a way to simplify it, but non of them seems to work, could someone point me some directions or hints?

much appreciated!

[UPDATE]

I'm trying to create a Kubernetes operator, which has some CRDs (Custom Resource Definitions), and since I create a generic controller that just take the CRDs and calling their functions (that's why I have interface), but I found I need to implement functions that are exactly the same, like `GetName`, `GetObject`, or some functions that manipulate the data and get back the results, and they're all the same across those CRD structs.

Comment: If the two method implementations are identical, that implies an underlying design flaw. However, it's impossible to say what that might be with a contrived example; we'd need to see the real code.

Comment: If it was not for the JSON argument you made, I'd recommend embedding. Looks like A and B have different JSON representations. You could still try dealing with JSON differences using a custom unmarshaler, but I suspect that won't be any cleaner. What you have now is at least more readable.

Comment: These methods have completely different implementations. Why would you want to combine them? Especially as these are just one-liners? What is your actual problem?

Comment: @Volker - the examples I show are indeed one liners, but they can be more, and they process same fields but for different structs, and the processing is exactly the same. That's why I want to see if there's a way to simply, of course I can create a non-receiver function like my 4 pointed out, but wanna see if there's a better way..

Comment: Yes @BurakSerdar , actually I'm creating a Kubernetes operator, and I found I end up with several structs (CRDs) that have same fields, and several functions that are exactly the same, so I'm looking for a way to remove the duplicates

Comment: But then it  is simple: 4. Write a function. That is what functions are good for: Code reuse. (Note that in Go code reuse happens through functions and not through inheritance.) The terms are "function" and "method" (not receiver function and non-receiver function).

Comment: thanks @Volker, yeah I was wondering if it's possible to have a method, since that way the method can access the fields inside the struct and also avoid the method being used outside of the struct, but I'll take creating a function to achieve my goal, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to just create a function that takes required parameters, and reuse the function across the structs, thanks for all the comments.

If you have other suggestions, please feel free to comment or suggest, thanks!